# Generating unattached dynamic components in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular14

I went through this issue while working on the ScheduleJS framework. At some point I am provided with a `HTMLCanvasElement` which I want to replace with a dynamically generated component programatically. To do so, and to keep the code as clean as possible, I'd like to create my own Angular components at runtime and use the `HTMLCanvasElement.replaceWith(component)` method from the provided `HTMLCanvasElement` replacing the canvas with the dynamically created component.

Here is the Angular service I came up with, which does the job the way I expected:

```
import {ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Injectable, Injector, Type} from "@angular/core";

import {ReplacementComponent} from "xxx"; // This is a higher order type of Component

@Injectable({providedIn: "root"})
export class DynamicComponentGenerator {

  // Attributes

  private _components: Map<string, ComponentRef<ReplacementComponent>> = new Map();
  private _currentKey: number = 0;

  // Constructor

  constructor(private _appRef: ApplicationRef,
              private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
              private _injector: Injector) { }

  // Methods

  create(componentType: Type<ReplacementComponent>): ComponentRef<ReplacementComponent> {
    const componentRef = componentType instanceof ComponentRef
      ? componentType
      : this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentType).create(this._injector);
    this._appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
    this._components.set(`${this._currentKey}`, componentRef);
    componentRef.instance.key = `${this._currentKey}`;
    this._currentKey += 1;
    return componentRef;
  }

  remove(componentKey: string): void {
    const componentRef = this._components.get(componentKey);
    if (componentRef) {
      this._appRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
      componentRef.destroy();
      this._components.delete(componentKey);
    }
  }

  clear(): void {
    this._components.forEach((componentRef, key) => {
      this._appRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView);
      componentRef.destroy();
      this._components.delete(key);
    });
    this._currentKey = 0;
  }

}
```

So basically this service lets me create a component with `.create(ComponentClass)` remove it by providing the component key `.remove(key)` and `clear()` to remove all the components.

My issues are the following:

- The `ComponentFactoryResolver` class is deprecated, should I use it anyways?
- Could not manage to use the newer API to create unattached components (not able to have access to an Angular hostView)
- Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: What Angular version are you talking about?

Comment: I'm running Angular 14 right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using new [createComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/createComponent) function:

```
import { createComponent, ... } from "@angular/core";

const componentRef = 
    createComponent(componentType, { environmentInjector: this._appRef.injector});
this._appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
```